# Как найти взвешенное среднее используя pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как вычислить среднее взвешенное значение? Дана таблица

```
staff_company = pd.DataFrame({'amount':[8,37,25,48,27,10]}, index = [22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47])
```

Индекс - это возраст сотрудников, столбец amount - количество сотрудников компании, нужно найти средний возраст сотрудников в компании. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать с помощью pandas и numpy

Comment: Индекс - это __суммарный__ возраст?

Answer (score 1):

Если индекс DataFrame'а - это **суммарный** возраст сотрудников, то:

```
In [50]: staff_company['age_avg'] = staff_company.index / staff_company.amount

In [51]: staff_company
Out[51]:
    amount   age_avg
22       8  2.750000
27      37  0.729730
32      25  1.280000
37      48  0.770833
42      27  1.555556
47      10  4.700000
```

иначе задача/вопрос не имеет смысла - либо возраст уже средний (и каждая строка - это данные по одной компании) либо это возраст конкретных сотрудников одной компании, но тогда непонятно что такое "количество сотрудников"...

Answer (score 1):

[MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu), спасибо за ответ, я уже разобрался :-)
Индекс - это просто возраст. Amount - это кол-во сотрудников данного возраста
Решение будет таким:

```
np.average(staff_company.index, weights=staff_company.amount)
```